# How can I find the max attribute across records in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, max, min

I have several records with several attributes (A, B, C, D).

I want to be able to find which record has the higher value for a given attribute, such as D.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you give us something more to work with? How are the records stored?

Comment: What if the 'x' number of records have the same max attribute value and I want to retrieve all the 'x' number of records?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might give [max_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max_by) a look.

```
objects = [some array of objects]

object_with_highest_value = objects.max_by {|obj| obj.desired_value }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many records do you have, it can be more efficient to perform the search on the DB. I would order by the desired attribute descending, and take the first record:

```
User.order('field DESC').first
```